# 404 Error after GitHub Repository File Update

Tags: github, repository, http-status-code-404

I'm using Github to host a profile page. When I updated pages within my index.html file the pages are now displaying as "404".

Steps taken:

1. Updated the index.html page with the new file names and saved the index file
2. Added a copy of the new files to the local repository folder
3. Performed `git add`, `commit` and `push` to send the new files to the GitHub repository - no errors showed

Please advise what I am omitting. Its been bout a year since I coded and my memory could use some help. Thanks

Comment: Git command line and status output -  

kutti@KGS-Belize MINGW64 ~/Documents/github/Kuttin4u.github.io/images (master)
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 829.25 KiB | 9.42 MiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
To https://github.com/Kuttin4u/Kuttin4u.github.io.git
   44715f3..f57de12  master -> master

Answer (score 0):

Error was found!
The index file was outside of the directory that contained the updated images - thus it did not get pushed to the repository. Performed the same repository upload step previously followed from the index file location and the pages now display.